# faster search for matching substrings in string column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, substring

I have a pyspark dataframe like the input dataframe below.  I'm splitting the `productname` column on whitespace and creating several new columns, from the tokens in the name. I have example code below.  I'm then self joining the dataframe on `first_token` equal to any of the other tokens, if it has the same `tz_brandname` and `producttype`. My goal is to match any two product names in the data if they have the same `tz_brandname` and `producttype`, and the first token matches any of the next 7 tokens in `productname`. I have example desired output below. My current code is extremely slow, does anyone have suggestions on how to speed this up?

Input Data:

```
products_productname_df.show()

+------------+-----------+-----------+
|tz_brandname|producttype|productname|
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |green duck |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand2      |game       |toy sky win|
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |duck black |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand2      |game       |sky flyer  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Output Data:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|tz_brandname|producttype|a_name     |b_name     |first_token|
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |duck black |green duck |duck       |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand2      |game       |sky flyer  |toy sky win|sky        |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, split, coalesce, size, length, substring

first_token_df=products_productname_df.withColumn('first_token', upper(trim(split('productname', '\s+')[0])))\
.withColumn('token_2', upper(trim(split('productname', '\s+')[1])))\
.withColumn('token_3', upper(trim(split('productname', '\s+')[2])))\
.withColumn('token_4', upper(trim(split('productname', '\s+')[3])))\
.withColumn('token_5', upper(trim(split('productname', '\s+')[4])))\
.withColumn('token_6', upper(trim(split('productname', '\s+')[5])))\
.withColumn('token_7', upper(trim(split('productname', '\s+')[6])))

block_df=first_token_df.alias('a')\
.join(first_token_df.alias('b'),
     (col('a.tz_brandname')==col('b.tz_brandname'))\
      &(col('a.producttype')==col('b.producttype'))\
      &(
     (col('a.first_token')==col('b.first_token'))\
         |(col('a.first_token')==col('b.token_2'))\
         |(col('a.first_token')==col('b.token_3'))\
         |(col('a.first_token')==col('b.token_4'))\
         |(col('a.first_token')==col('b.token_5'))\
         |(col('a.first_token')==col('b.token_6'))\
         |(col('a.first_token')==col('b.token_7'))
     ),
        how='inner'      
     )\
      .select(
     col('a.tz_brandname'),
         col('a.producttype'),
         col('a.productname').alias('a_name'),
         col('b.productname').alias('b_name'),
         col('a.first_token')
     )


block_df[upper(trim(block_df['first_token']))!=upper(trim(block_df['b_name']))].distinct().orderBy('a_name').show(truncate=False)
```

update:

incorporating array_intersect, still runs pretty slow

```
    block_df=products_productname_df[['tz_brandname','producttype','productname']].distinct()
    
    block_df=block_df.alias('a')\
    .join(block_df.alias('b'),
          (col('a.tz_brandname')==col('b.tz_brandname'))\
          &(col('a.producttype')==col('b.producttype'))\
          &(size(array_intersect(split(col('a.productname'),''),split(col('b.productname'),'')))>0)
         ,
          how='inner'
         )\
    .select(
    col('a.tz_brandname'),
        col('a.producttype'),
        col('a.productname').alias('a_name'),
col('b.productname).alias('b_name'),
        array_intersect(split(col('a.productname'),''),split(col('b.productname'),'')).alias('intersect_tokens')
    ).distinct()
```

Comment: I have no skills in the tech you listed, but one could sort the input list by the first 2 columns. The rest would be straight forward loop in the result.  Note: Not sure about your 3rd result column.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with `pyspark.sql.functions.explode()` so it's a simpler join instead of one which has to compare a bunch of conditions for each pair.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want exactly to but you'd better use the array functions.

```
df = spark.read.csv('test.csv', header=True)
df.show()

+------------+-----------+-----------+
|tz_brandname|producttype|productname|
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|      brand1|        toy| green duck|
|      brand2|       game|toy sky win|
|      brand1|        toy| duck black|
|      brand2|       game|  sky flyer|
|      brand2|       game| flyer test|
+------------+-----------+-----------+

df.withColumnRenamed('productname', 'a_name') \
  .join(df.withColumnRenamed('productname', 'b_name'), ['tz_brandname', 'producttype'], 'inner') \
  .filter('a_name > b_name') \
  .withColumn('first_token', f.array_intersect(f.split('a_name', ' '), f.split('b_name', ' '))) \
  .show()

+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|tz_brandname|producttype|     a_name|    b_name|first_token|
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|      brand1|        toy| green duck|duck black|     [duck]|
|      brand2|       game|toy sky win|flyer test|         []|
|      brand2|       game|toy sky win| sky flyer|      [sky]|
|      brand2|       game|  sky flyer|flyer test|    [flyer]|
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: thanks for getting back to me on this.  I added an update to my original post, using your array_intersect suggestion, to try to illustrate my goal.  I want to get all the productnames side by side if they share tokens and their tz_brandname and producttype match.  With your suggestion I think we're only comparing the first and last productnames for each combination of tz_brandname and prdoucttype.

Comment: I have modified my answer, to give the all combination and you can use the result as you wish. Group by or any other way.